# Oracle SYSDATE input data type

Tags: oracle, plsql

Form the client I need to pass a SYSDATE argument to PL/SQL. In the server it need to be converted to date, for which iam using TO_DATE(in_timestamp, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'); What should be the data type of in_timestamp?

Comment: :If you are passing `SYSDATE` to `in_timestamp` then datatype will be of `DATE` type .Are you returnig the same variable after converting it ?

Comment: i will not be returning any value from procedure.

Comment: :then go for `date` as mentioned by `Erkan Haspulat` in his answer

Comment: Do you mean SYSDATE, the oracle pseudo-column, or just a system generated date?

Comment: Naming something in_timestamp when you are looking for a data may be confusion. People may think you are asking for a `timestamp` instead of a `date`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SYSDATE` is itself a `date`, and it seems like the target field is also a `date` (Since you used `TO_DATE()`). Thus you don't actually need a conversion here.

Just pass `SYSDATE` and use it in your PL/SQL block, meaning `in_timestamp` should be a date.

Answer (score 0):

As far as TO_DATE is concerned you can have CHAR, VARCHAR or VARCHAR2(recommended) basically it should be of **String** type as following examples suggest:-

```
to_date('2003/07/09', 'yyyy/mm/dd') would return a date value of July 9, 2003.
to_date('070903', 'MMDDYY') would return a date value of July 9, 2003.
to_date('20020315', 'yyyymmdd') would return a date value of Mar 15, 2002.
```

You can find more information related to TO_DATE at [this link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php),

**EDIT**

*"However, if you are passing sysdate you dont't need to use TO_DATE again because it is already a Date value..."*as mentioned by @Gaurav and Hence the **dataType** of in_timestamp should be DATE..

Comment: :If he's passing sysdate then why he should be recommmended to  store that in varchar*?,